# C++: Get index of char element in array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I need to get number of character in array.

```
const char myarray[5] = {'0', 'a', 'e', 'f', 'c'}; // Create array of char
int number=0; // Create variable
number = getposition(myarray, 'f'); // Now number equals to 3
number = getposition(myarray, 'z'); // -1, because array doesn't have this char
```

My task is easy because array don't have repeating characters (for example, it can't be smth like this: {'a', '1', 'f', 'a'}). How can I do it?

Comment: You mean 'the indices of a character'?

Comment: You could return an array of position.

Comment: Yes. Not indices, but one index: as I've said, there are no repeating characters.

Comment: `memchr` is your friend - unless this is homework - in which case - you should think about it....

Comment: No, this is an algorhythm of decoding. I can make construction with a hundreds of if or use case, but I think there could be more effective decision.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A little bit more C++:

```
#include <algorithm>

int getposition(const char *array, size_t size, char c)
{
     const char* end = array + size;
     const char* match = std::find(array, end, c);
     return (end == match)? -1 : (match-array);
}
```

A lot more C++:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
int getposition(const T (&array)[N], const T c)
{
     const T* match = std::find(array, array+N, c);
     return (array+N==match)? -1 : std::distance(array, match);
}
```

### Bonus C++11/C++11 update

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <typename Range, typename T>
size_t index_of(Range const& range, T const& c) {
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    auto b = begin(range), e = end(range);
    auto match = std::find(b, e, c);

    return (e==match)? -1 : std::distance(b, match);
}
```

### Bonus C++17 update

Here, the original question gets direct support in `std::string_view`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac18c3aadaae28e6)</kbd>**

```
#include <string_view>
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main() {
    return "hello"sv.find('e');
}
```

Comment: The first is really the only correct answer in C++.  If the question were in C, then the response is `memchr` (mentioned by another poster).  The problem is a classical linear search, and you don't reinvent the wheel (unless that is the target of the exercise).

Comment: The first one here is definitely wrong, since it uses `strlen` instead of the `size` parameter, and we don't know whether the array is a string (the one in the example isn't) and if so whether the 0 terminator is supposed to be searched or not. But otherwise it's basically the right thing. You could have an "even more C++" version using `std::begin(array), std::end(array)`, although then it also wouldn't need to advertise the template deduction trick for capturing `N`, because it could just take a single template argument `Range`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Hehe. Can you tell I copied that from the OP... That's what I deserve for copy-pasting without reading it well :( Fixed. About the Range-based version, I considered adding it (but I was already at 2 options, and it turns out speed matters at SO)

Comment: In the second code block, end is not defined. However, in the first code block, it is defined. Did I miss something here?

Comment: @JamesLittle Wow. How did that go unnoticed for all these years. I took the opportunity to add c++11, c++14 and c++17 versions that are informative and more elegant, respectively! Cheers

Comment: @sehe Awesome, glad I wasn't going crazy. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, size_t size>
int getposition(T const (&array)[size], T const & c)
{
    T const * found = std::find(&array[0], &array[size], c);
    return found == &array[size] ? -1 : found - array;
}
```

Comment: Very nice but quite cryptic ;)

Comment: I really want to +1 this, if only `found - array` were replaced by `std::distance(array,found)`.

Comment: @xtofl: I don't really see any point in that - this function specifically deals with an array, not a generic iterator range.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I edited the post : `the type T was missing in the second parameter`. Hope it is okay with you.

Comment: @Nawaz: no it wasn't; I've rolled back to remove the duplicated `T`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oops. Yeah. I didn't notice it is `T const` as opposed to `const T` (which made me think that `T` is missing after `const`).

Comment: @xtofl: I assume you were the one who upvoted my (otherwise identical) answer then :) Sometimes SO makes me wonder how some posts get more attention than others, while posted simultaneously

Answer (score 5):

You need to tell the `getposition()` method how many elements to search within the array and as the array is initialised at compile time you can use the `sizeof` directive:

```
int number = getposition(myarray, sizeof(myarray), 'f');

...

int getposition(const char *array, size_t size, char c)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == c)
            return (int)i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Using more than one return in a function doesn't help maintenance and legibility.

Comment: @m0skit0: That's a matter of preference. IMO saving the value in an extra var and exiting the loop when you know that you can return immediately doesn't help either.

Comment: @m0skit0: adding extra variables and `break` statements wouldn't help either.

Comment: Why extra varibles wouldn't help. And I don't use any `break` statements

Comment: @m0skit0: You'd need to add a `break` (or a more complicated termination condition), and a variable to store the return value, in order to follow your advice and avoid an early return. Or do you have a suggestion that avoids an early return and somehow manages to be more legible than this?

Comment: @Jon It's not really a question of preference.  In a more complicated case, naming in the condition avoids additional comments.  And in this case, of course, you need neither the extra variable nor the extra return; the classical linear search (`while ( !finished && !condition ) next;` works quite well.

Comment: @Mike: you don't need to add any break. Check my answer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: True, but "no more than one return" is a religious opinion, not one based on practical considerations. There are infinitely many function bodies, and infinitely many of them require special modifications just so the single `return` can be achieved.

Comment: I happen to agree with the single return concept, but not in trivial functions like this where maintenance is not a consideration, given the size of the function.  I don't think @m0skit0 has really provided the 'proof' that a single `return` is king - his answer is way more complicated than it needs to be and maintenance would be a  real concern.

Comment: I don't see that "way" more complicated thing anywhere. Just one more variable... Anyway, you're maybe right.

Comment: @m0skit0: Two more variables. And a bit of extra code to undo the off-by-one error you introduce. Sometimes an early return really is the clearest thing to do, even if it was briefly unfashionable thirty years ago.

Comment: Since you're engaged in style wars with m0skit0 anyway: you shouldn't mix `int` with `size_t`, since the latter might be a larger type than the former. There isn't a type guaranteed to be able to represent every value of `size_t` and also an extra "no result" value, but there are better approaches to that goal than `int`.

Comment: Probably `ssize_t`, but I kept to `int` as that is what the OP was using.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd forgotten that he queestioner  made the same error, although in the calling code rather than in `getposition` itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
int getposition(const char* a, int arr_size, char to_find)
{
    int pos = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
    {
        if(a[i] == to_find)
        {
            pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Won't even compile... And that's no function. Please make sure of your answers before posting ;)

Comment: Updated with something that compiles and works. My first answer was, frankly, rubbish. The other answers are also much cleverer than mine :-)

Comment: @m0skit0: your answer won't compile either; do you know the saying 'people in glass houses...'?

Answer (score 1):

If this really is a pure decoding exercise - why not re-organize your array... then lookup is constant time - e.g..

```
int lt[128]; // ignoring negative values..

memset(lt, -1, 128); // initialize all to -1

// set the ones you want mappings for..
lt['0'] = 0;
lt['a'] = 1;
lt['e'] = 2;
lt['f'] = 3;
lt['c'] = 4;
```

so now your look up function is:

```
int indexOf(char v) { return lt[v]; }
```

You'd be hard-pressed to beat that for performance...

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the array size as well to the function.

```
int getposition(const char* array, size_t array_size, char value)
{
    int ret = -1;

    int i = 0;
    bool found = false;
    while (i < array_size && !found)
    {
        found = (array[i++] == value);
    }

    if (found)
    {
        ret = i - 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: :) seems we both overcomplated things: the first occurence will do.

Comment: I'm returning on the first occurence mate ;) The while() loop end on first occurence. Don't downvote without actually understanding the code ;) And I didn't downvote you btw because your answer was a valid one. I simply critized the form :P

Comment: Sorry - I read over the `!found` condition.  Adding an explicit `return` would have prevented that :).  But I downvoted because you wrote the function instead of using the standard library.

Comment: Curiously enough, trojanfoe didn't get any downvote from you. And I don't want to add an extra `return`, that's the point ;)

Comment: @m0skit0: You have some errors in your answer:  the input array should be `const char *`.  You shouldn't initialise an `unsigned` type (`ret`) with `-1` and `boolean` isn't a valid C++ keyword. This question was about the size of an array, not how to program dogmatically.

Comment: What a shame on me! True and fixed. Well, you program as you want as I do program as I want. You'll probably understand some day why multiple returns are not desirable. Until then, I'll upvote your comment ;)

Comment: It's ironic that you critique other peoples answers so much and yet have so many problems with your own answer.  You tell people about maintainability, legibility and even that their code doesn't compile, and yet your own answer shows all these faults.  I wouldn't have even noticed the errors in your code if you had been less vocal, so perhaps in future turn it down a notch.

Comment: I'm sorry but my code has no maintainability or legibility issues. It's true I wrote it too fast and I speak too much, but I can excuse my self because I'm at work and coding in Java, Perl, SQL and I got stuff get mixed. But I won't excuse myself. Anyway, the question has been answered and my answer got downvoted rightfully, so I'm out of this discussion. Have fun coding :)